# Email submit input clearing/css doesn't work on iphone Safari or Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a simple `email input` and `submit button` on a site. When I submit on the `web application`, everything works. When I submit on my `iOS phone`, `javascript/css` DOESN'T work for the submission if the `email` is valid, but the `javascript/css` DOES work if the email is invalid.

I've been trying to debug this thing for a while!

HTML:

```
<input name="_replyto" placeholder="your email address">
<button id="submitBtn" value="getaccess" onclick="handleEmailSubmit()"> get access</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function handleEmailSubmit(){
    if( validateEmail($('input').val()) ) {
        var clientEmail=$('input').val();
        console.log('sending request...')
        csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content');  
        $('input').addClass('submitBtnFlashGreen')
        $('input').val('Got it. Thanks!')
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input').val('');
            $('input').addClass('submitBtnUnflash')
        },800); 
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input').removeClass('submitBtnFlashGreen');
            $('input').removeClass('submitBtnUnflash')
        },1500);      
        $('input').val('');

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/signup",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{
                _csrf:csrfToken,
                email:clientEmail
            },
            success:function(response){
                console.log('done!')
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('input').addClass('submitBtnFlash')
        $('input').val('email is invalid')
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input').val('');
            $('input').addClass('submitBtnUnflash')
        },800); 
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('input').removeClass('submitBtnFlash');
            $('input').removeClass('submitBtnUnflash')
        },1500); 
    }    
}
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the missing ']' causes an error in the line:

```
csrfToken = $('meta[name="csrf-token"').attr('content');
```